# Return sorted indexes skipping nan values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data set:

```
PID,RUN_START_DATE,PUSHUP_START_DATE,SITUP_START_DATE,PULLUP_START_DATE
1,2013-01-24,2013-01-02,,2013-02-03
2,2013-01-30,2013-01-21,2013-01-13,2013-01-06
3,2013-01-29,2013-01-28,2013-01-01,2013-01-29
4,2013-02-16,2013-02-12,2013-01-04,2013-02-11
5,2013-01-06,2013-02-07,2013-02-25,2013-02-12
6,2013-01-26,2013-01-28,2013-02-12,2013-01-10
7,2013-01-26,,2013-01-12,2013-01-30
8,2013-01-03,2013-01-24,2013-01-19,2013-01-02
9,2013-01-22,2013-01-13,2013-02-03,
10,2013-02-06,2013-01-16,2013-02-07,2013-01-11
```

I know I can use `numpy.argsort` to return the sorted indexes of the values:

```
SQ_AL_INDX = numpy.argsort(df_sequence[['RUN_START_DATE', 'PUSHUP_START_DATE', 'SITUP_START_DATE', 'PULLUP_START_DATE']], axis=1)
```

...returns...

```
   RUN_START_DATE  PUSHUP_START_DATE  SITUP_START_DATE  PULLUP_START_DATE
0               2                  1                 0                  3
1               3                  2                 1                  0
2               2                  1                 0                  3
3               2                  3                 1                  0
4               0                  1                 3                  2
5               3                  0                 1                  2
6               1                  2                 0                  3
7               3                  0                 2                  1
8               3                  1                 0                  2
9               3                  1                 0                  2
```

But, it seems to put `pandas.NaT` values into the first position.  So in this example `where PID == 1` the sort order returns `2 1 0 3`.  But, the second index position is a `pandas.Nat` value.

How can I get the sorted indexes while skipping the `pandas.NaT` values (e.g., the return index values would be `2 1 np.NaN 3` or `2 1 pandas.NaT 3` or better yet `1 0 2` for `PID 1` instead of `2 1 0 3`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `numpy.argsort` to the `apply` method instead of using it directly. This way, NaNs/NaTs persist. For your example:

```
In [2]: df_sequence[['RUN_START_DATE', 'PUSHUP_START_DATE', 'SITUP_START_DATE', 'PULLUP_START_DATE']].apply(numpy.argsort, axis=1)
Out[2]: 
                RUN_START_DATE  PUSHUP_START_DATE  SITUP_START_DATE  PULLUP_START_DATE
0               1                  0               NaN               2
(etc.)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  When I run the code I get and odd result on lines with NaT on them.  For line 0 I get the following:  0  1970-01-01 00:00:00  1970-01-01 00:00:00  2262-04-10 0:12:43.145224  1970-01-01 00:00:00.  Line 6 and 8 are also wrong. I have put my code and the full result on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/qhhZzRGr

Comment: can u show df.dtypes and your pandas version? this should work in 0.11, may not in 0.10.1; try on current master if u can

Comment: @jeff, The originals are datetime64[ns] and the return index after the apply are objects.  I ma using version 0.11.0.dev-3790f16.

Comment: thanks. I opened an issue because series.argsort() should work correctly. (I know u r using np.argsort) but that doesn't handle the NaT at all https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2967

Comment: you are getting those funny looking times because they are the NaT  presented in buggy numpy 1.6.2 (know display issue) - till we fix the above issue (and u use series.argsort), no easy workaround

Comment: continued - except you could mask yourself (eg isnull(df)) then just ignore the true values - eg they have nans

Comment: @Jeff thank you much.  I went with holding off to do the date conversion until the very last part of my script.  I then work with the np.argsort() values as strings.  It is sloppy, but it works for now. :) Thank you much!

Comment: actually you might do an astype('object') and I think this might work (just a workaround)